# Home page in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I had created a module. I n that module I created a view. Now I need that view should be act as a home page. I am unable to set it as home page of my orchard application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Provided the solution to me. I thank it](https://boringguys.wordpress.com/2014/08/27/how-to-set-an-orchard-cms-module-to-be-home-page-with-code/)